# Unsupported class file major version 61, trying to migrate from Java 11 to Java 17

Tags: java, maven, quarkus

I try to migrate a Java 11 project to Java 17. With Java 11 environment, the project runs without any issues. But in Java 17 I get the following error:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.791 s <<< FAILURE! - in userservice.controller.UserControllerTest
userservice.controller.UserControllerTest  Time elapsed: 1.791 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize Arc
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.spi.EnhancementException: Failed to enhance class userservice.persistence.entities.UserEntity
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
```

My UserEntity class looks like this:

```
package userservice.persistence.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity(name="user")
@Table(name="user")
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM user u ORDER BY u.email")
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findByEmail", query = "SELECT u FROM user u WHERE u.email = :email")
public class UserEntity {

    public static final String QUERY_FIND_ALL = "User.findAll";
    public static final String QUERY_FIND_BY_EMAIL = "User.findByEmail";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    public UserEntity() {}

    // basic setter, getter for email and id...
    // and basic equals, toString and hashCode methods...

}
```

What am I missing..would be glad if someone could help me.

Edit:
Here are the Dependencies I use in the quarkus project:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-kubernetes</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-container-image-docker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-test-h2</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-mysql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-liquibase</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-oidc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5-mockito</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
      <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-test-security</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>own.repo.costcenter</groupId>
      <artifactId>common-lib</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: It seems that your version of Hibernate doesn't support  Java 17 yet. It seems that only [5.6, 6.1 and newer support Java 17](https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/#compatibility-matrix). Which version are you using?

Comment: looks as if some of your _org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance_ dependency cannot cope with bytecode produced by Java 17. Can you add the dependencies and their versions that you have that could contain that package or Exception class? (Please also have a look into transitive deps)

Comment: That means `Unsupported class file major version 61` you are using a JDK less than 17 ... Is that a spring boot project?

Comment: I use: openjdk 17.0.4 2022-07-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-17.0.4.8.1 (build 17.0.4+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-17.0.4.8.1 (build 17.0.4+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: I add all used dependencies and how can I find out which hibernate version am I using?

Comment: @quinzo: it seems you only have hibernate as a transient dependency. You need to use something like `dependency:tree` to find out which version of hibernate you end up using and then either update that directly or update to a newer version of whatever ends up pulling in hibernate that depends on a newever version.

Comment: @khmarbaise normally this is the reason, appears to be hibernate here

Answer (score 2):

Well my problem was that I forget to update my quarkus dependency. Hope this will help someone in the future :)